# How to show that a test statistics can't reject H0 with a small change in the hypothesized value

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

In the homework, suppose the null hypothesis is given by
$H_{0\text{ }}: \alpha =\alpha _{0}$,
and a test statistics $T\left( x\right) $ is proposed. The question is to
show that $T\left( x\right) $ can't reject $H_{0\text{ }}$ if $\alpha
=\alpha _{0}+\varepsilon $ where $\varepsilon $ is a small number, I am a
little lost at this. Any help will be highly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: As it is, I don't think this makes any sense. I imagine you're missing assumptions. Is this from a textbook? Chapter and exercise number?

Comment: Sorry, this is not directly from some textbooks, but it is a question the professor mentioned in class. I am also not quite understand this question. Is it related to the local power of the test statistics?

Comment: As it stands, I don't think there's enough information to answer the question. Are you assuming a normal distribution? How "small" is "small"?

Comment: Yes, I can think it as a normal, and ε could be 1/n where n is the sample size.